# Handling, removing and adding UILabels while using UIView Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I got another issue with my Control for a timeline application.

There is a certain Amount of UILabels on my TimelineView which herited from UIView.

I Implemented a Scrolling function and it works quite fine. When an Element reaches the Bottom it gets deleted and another UILabel is added above the first one and the other way around.There is a labels Array in the Classes delegate where all UIlabels(TimeLabels) are stored and removed.(Important for later implementation of hours/days etc - dynamic loading so that the memory usage will be low)

Now I want to do an ease out animation after releasing the touchgesture (via touchesEnded), with a certain amount of speed, which is calculated correctly. It works quite fine with an UIView Animation:

```
speed/=3;
for(TimeLabel *movingLabel in self.delegate.labels){
    NSLog(@"%i",movingLabel.time);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];


    CGRect movingFrame = [[movingLabel.layer presentationLayer] frame];
    NSLog(@"%f",movingFrame.origin.y);

    movingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(7, movingLabel.frame.origin.y+speed, 200, 25);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Animation is done for all Labels correctly.

**BUT** when I want to expand my method (not shown above) so that when a label's position drops beneath the application's frame height, it wont be dropped (even using the presentationLayer which, according to other people, is a possibility of getting the current Position while animating. But it only shows the endposition of every Label when logging...).

So my question:Is it even possible to remove a UILabel by checking it's position while animating it? AND as important as that question: Is it possible to insert a new UILabel and e.g. add the removed labels layer so the started animation can resume with the new one?

And if those things are not possible: Is there another way to achieve an ease out animation like that without implementing a whole new Animation?

It's a bit hard to explain how it should exactly look like but I hope I could describe my problem properly and there is anyone who's able to help me.

Greetings,

Âsgaroth

Comment: You should try moving the begin and commit outside of the for loop along with the UIView animation properties.

Comment: Didn't change it. thanks for the tipp anyway

Comment: Ah right was worth a try either way though its much more efficient to put the begin and commit outside of the for loop :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the animation to complete at a different y position in some cases.  The simple way to do that (if I understand the question correctly) is to compute y position at which you want the label to be removed, animate to there, and add...

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

You said "drops beneath the frame height".  Is that the frame height of the label's superview?  If so, set the ending position of `label.frame.origin.y` to `label.superview.bounds.size.height`

Comment: Tried at seems to be the best solution for me at the time. Thank you very much!